# How can I achieve the effect of a double line going through some text but not on top of it? Image in description

Tags: html, css

I've found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSIRX.jpg) styling done to a heading text which I figure is a double border that is going through the text but isn't overlapping with it. Does anyone know how can I do the same to my h1 element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution:

```css
    h1 {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
     }
    h1:before {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      height: 6px;
      width: 40%;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      left: 0;
      top: 40%;
    }
    h1:after {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      height: 6px;
      width: 40%;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      right: 0;
      top: 40%;
    }
```

```html
    <h1>Title</h1>
```

Comment: My bad! Completely lost my train of thought when coding. Main answer updated - you can also use calc with the % widths to guarantee no overlap if it needs to be responsive.